# Why can't perform an Array validation through a function inside an if statement?

Tags: node.js, arrays, typescript

Let me explain myself, I'm using nodejs, express and typescript btw.

I have this function in my controller:

```
async function update(req: Request, res: Response, options: JsonModel = {}, relatedModels?: RelatedModels[]) {
  try {
    /* ...some_code */

    if (validateArray(relatedModels)) {
      await updateRelatedModels(relatedModels, data);
    }

    /* ...more_code */
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error);
  }
};
```

Notice that the `relatedModels` has a `?` in the params.

Why does this does work:

```
if (Array.isArray(relatedModels) && relatedModels.length > 0) {
  await updateRelatedModels(relatedModels, data);
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
if (validateArray(relatedModels)) {
  await updateRelatedModels(relatedModels, data);
}
```

This is the error message I'm getting when trying to do that:

```
Argument of type 'RelatedModels[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RelatedModels[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'RelatedModels[]'.
```

if `validateArray()` has the exact same validation inside:

```
// check if array is an Array and if not empty
export const validateArray = (array: undefined | any[]): boolean => Array.isArray(array) && array.length > 0;
```

The meaning of my code is to run that `await updateRelatedModels(...)` function if the array is a valid array and not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `undefined` as another type of relatedModels parameter.

```
async update(req: Request, res: Response, options: JsonModel = {}, relatedModels: RelatedModels[] | undefined) {
        //your code...
};
```

This is because you are using `undefined` in validateArray function parameters.

```
export const validateArray = (array: undefined | any[]): boolean => Array.isArray(array) && array.length > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because TypeScript limits advanced type narrowing to the current block only. Otherwise it would take them forever to do type narrowing of your code and you would experience much longer build times. In your scenario you can use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (`is` operator):

```js
export const validateArray =
  (array: undefined | any[]): array is any[] =>
    Array.isArray(array) && array.length > 0;
```

See this [example in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wG4EMA2BLAEyxmAEEoosBPOAXgCg44AKLC6gLjgFdkDgAZnmTACcAD5wsyKgG0AugEoubSjTyopMhXQB8jJnHJqAdBuPVW7KorgAyO1OsmcwZAHMYACzi64ABgBuenpXeFUudChhdx1JXn4hEQJgvAEWbHwiEgsqKyhFW1UTMG5UL2ZFQKA).